# How to set same view file for different actions in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

Hello friends I am new in zf2 and unable to call same view file for dynamic action. Basically my url is "http://localhost:8084/g/raj" but the last one is raj that is changing. But I want to call single view file from different module.
Just want to change last action but call same view file.
I have used this code but it is not working.It redirected to home page.I want to change only view file without changing url.

```
 $result = new ViewModel();
 $result->setTemplate('Application/IndexController/index');
 return $result;
```

Please give any reply.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your setTemplate() you have to send path of your template and not the action.

```
$result = new ViewModel();
$result->setTemplate('path/to/my/view');
return $result;
```

(you probably search a path like: application/index/index.phtml)

Comment: you don't need the full path, only the path after the folder view

Comment: I have given this path "Students/students/students/students.phtml" but not working.

Comment: can you tell me where is your template and your controller? if you work with zf2, you only should have something like students/students/students.phtml

Comment: This is a different module named Students.That have two controller and two views.I am calling this from different module controller.

Comment: can i use this  return $this->forward()->dispatch('Students\Controller\Students', 
        array('action' => 'index')); but in this code an error is occurring Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Students\Controller\StudentsController

Comment: ok, if you call the view from another module, you have to declare the template path to your module, use in your module config: 'template_map' => array( 'name/my/template' => => \_\_DIR\_\_ . '/../../Students/view/students/students/students.phtml')  like that you can setTemplate('name/my/template');

Comment: I have putted the code but what is in setTemplate() function?

Comment: by default, zf2 know that in module __Student__ , in __StudentsController__ with __studentssAction()__, the template is here: student/students/studentss.phtml, setTemplate say to zf2 that the template is not here and must be find at setTemplate('find/my/path').